# How to check the path which has been a running process?

Tags: linux, bash, process, path, pid

At the begining apologize for my English.

I have a running process on server, and when I execute:

```
ps -aux | grep script.sh
```

I get such a result:

```
root     28104  0.0  0.0 106096  1220 pts/7    S+   08:27   0:00 /bin/bash ./script.sh
```

But this script is running from eg. /home/user/my/program/script.sh

So, how I can get the full path of from where the script was running? I have many scripts which name is exactly same, but they are running from different locations and I need to know from where the given script was running.

Thanks for reply!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following script:

```
for each in `pidof script.sh`
do
   readlink /proc/$each/cwd
done
```

This will find the pid.s of all script.sh scripts running and find the corresponding cwd (current working directories) for /proc.

Answer (score 2):

use pwdx 
usage:  pwdx pid ...
  (show process working directory)
for example,

```
pwdx 20102
```

where 20102 is the pid 
this will show the process working directory of the process

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

#declare the associative array with PID as key and process directory as value
declare -A dirr

#This will get the pid of the script
pid_proc=($(ps -eaf | grep "$1.sh" | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $2}'))


for PID in ${pid_proc[@]}
do
    #using Debasish method
    dirr[$PID]=$(pwdx $PID)
    # Below are different process to get the CWD of running process
    # using user1984289 method
    #dirr[$PID]=$(readlink /proc/"$PID"/cwd)
    #dirr[$PID]=$(cd /proc/$PID/cwd; /bin/pwd)
done

# iterate using the keys of the associative and get the working directory
for PID in "${!dirr[@]}"
do
 echo "The script '$1.sh' with PID:'$PID' is in the directory '${dirr[$PID]}'"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pgrep` to get the PIDs of your instances, and then read the link of the associated `CWD` directory. Basically, the same approach as @user1984289 but using `pgrep` instead of `pidof` which does not match bash script names on my system (even with the `-x` option):

```
for pid in $(pgrep -f foo.sh); do readlink /proc/$pid/cwd; done
```

Just change `foo.sh` to the name of your script.